# I can't open my mailbox in Gmail through my Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: server, firefox, email, gmail

For the past few years my desktop has been running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have been using the Mozilla Firefox browser without any problem. Suddenly, however, I find myself unable to open my mailbox in Gmail.

I can quickly get to the Gmail Login page, but when I type in my Username and Password the red circular loading indicator keeps turning for an abnormally long time and finally the message comes up : "Problem Loading Page - Mozilla Firefox" and "Server Not Found". Under the latter message there are various suggestions -- such as the ones that ask me to type the web address correctly, check Firewall and proxy settings, etc. -- none of which seems to apply to my case, especially because my problem is a sudden development.

Surprisingly, I can freely access all other sites, including  Rediffmail and Yahoo Mail accounts.

I have come across another post describing  exactly the same problem. Various solutions have been  suggested to it but, being a novice, I can't understand them well and am wary of trying any of them. Could anyone suggest a solution in simple language?

Comment: Have you tried stuff like cleaning out your cache and website data? Beyond that, it's worth checking that you can resolve gmail.com (ping it from a terminal: ping gmail.com)

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Firefox ?

Comment: Is the problem limited to  Firefox? Have you tried (just for debugging issues) other browsers like chromium or chrome?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Firefox Addons you might have installed?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of Firefox,  I have cleaned out my cache, and my Firefox setting is "Never Remember History". There are only two add-ons, viz., AdBlock (which I disabled) and Ubuntu Modifications (which I didn't mess with). I have tried  the command   "ping google.com" followed by Control C to stop continuous output, and then "ping 209.85.225.105" followed by Control C. I have downloaded and tried both Chrome and Chromium, but the problem persists.